# Rebase two branches on other branch (not master)

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have the following commit history:

```
---> master
  \
   ---------> setting-envs
        \
         -----> feature1
               \
                -----> feature2
```

Now, I need changes from `setting-envs` in `feature1` and `feature2`. However, rebasing `feature1` on `setting-envs` branch will change commit history on `feature1`, thus, I won't be then able to properly rebase `feature2` on `feature1` as they will have different commit history (except for `setting-envs` branch). Is there any way to rebase both `feature1` and `feature2` branches on `setting-envs` branch without messing the commit history? Something like this:

```
---> master
  \
   ---------> setting-envs
             \
              -----> feature1
                    \
                     -----> feature2
```

Comment: First rebase `feature1` on `master` then `feature2` on `feature1`

Comment: Rebase `feature2` and simply move pointer `feature1`.

Comment: @phd You're right, I read your linked answer and it's indeed simpler. Love it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with all flags that you can put on rebase but I think you can go with this (practical approach):

I'l assume that `feature2` had 3 commits after was created out of `feature1` we'll call them A,B, C

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase setting-envs // after this step feature1's commits have changed
// now lets handle feature2:
git branch -m feature2 feature2_backup  // rename the branch
git checkout -b feature2 // checkout out 'new' branch point out of feature1
git cherry-pick A 
git cherry-pick B
git cherry-pick C 
git branch -D feature2_backup
```

Of course you can use one cherry-pick instead of three but in general since actual new changes were introduced into feature1 after it was rebased, you might have conflicts after each commit so I personally prefer to handle them one by one (a matter of taste).